# How do I define a different database path for iPad/iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios

This is the way I define the path to my local sql database.
However what I noticed is that the simulator in both iPhone and iPad mode share the same database.

```
- (NSString *)recordArchivePath
{
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"store.data"];
}


NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

NSString *path = [self recordArchivePath];
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *options = @{
                           NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                         };
sqliteStore = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
```

What do I have to do have a different database for each mode?

I have tried this approach, which also failed:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"store.data"];
#else
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"store-ipad.data"];
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#define IS_IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

Then you can use

```
if (IS_IPAD) {
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"store-ipad.data"];
} else {
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"store.data"];
}
```